# Partitioned Matrix-Vector Multiplication

Tags: c++, performance, matrix, parallel-processing

Given a very sparse *nxn* matrix `A` with *nnz(A)* non-zeros, and a dense *nxn* matrix `B`. I would like to compute the matrix product `AxB`. Since *n* is very large, if carried out naively, the dense matrix `B` cannot be put into the memory. I have the following two options, but not sure which one is better. Could you give some suggestions. Thanks.

Option1. I parition the matrix `B` into *n* column vectors `[b1,b2,...,bn]`. Then, I can put matrix `A` and any single vector `bi` into the memory, and calculate the `A*b1, A*b2, ..., A*bn`, respectively.

Option2. I partition the matrices `A` and `B`, respectively, into four *n/2Xn/2* blocks, and then use the block matrix-matrix multiplications to calculate `A*B`.

Which of the above choice is better? Can I say that Option 1 has high performance in parallel calculation?

Comment: ...use Eigen, Armedillo, or some other 3rd party matrix library rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Currently, I may want to know the performance comparison of the above two choices.

Comment: Order of magnitude of n might be useful...  Apparently `root(n)` will fit into memory?  So perhaps it's really just out of the bounds of a typical (16 GB) working memory set?  n is maybe 10^21 or less?

Comment: `n` may be approximately 2M.

Comment: Then http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations There you go. Method 1 is essentially Schoolbook long multiplication, method 2 is worse than Karatsubas algorithm.

Comment: How about Method 1 compared with Method 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

See a discussion of both approaches, though for two dense matrices, in [this document](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawnspdf/lawn129.pdf) from the Scalapack documentation. Scalapack is the one of the reference tools for distributed linear algebra.